# UITableView Swipe Action is not working when user begin swiping on the UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiswipeactionsconfiguration

I have implemented `UITableView` with left swipe actions for each `TableViewCell`. For implementing left swipe action, I used following delegate method which is provided by the apple.

```
-(NSArray *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

}
```

[image]

Above is the screen capture of my storyboard. Which shows the `UITableViewCell` UI design. My swipe action is working without any problem except one occasion. That is, as you can see here, on the right hand side I have included a thumbnail image (`UIImageView`). Once user begin swiping by tapping on this image, the swipe action is not working. I have tried with disable user interactions for image view as well, but still swipe action isn't working. Anyone have an idea what's wrong with my implementation is?

I have create `UITableViewCell` class and set UIOutlet to the image view. I'm downloading the image from url using custom method and set in to the `UIImageView`. Following code snippet will explain that.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imgProductIcon;

[self.imgProductIcon setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:item.itemImage] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ICProduct"]];

- (void)setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url
       placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholderImage
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request addValue:@"image/*" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

    [self setImageWithURLRequest:request placeholderImage:placeholderImage success:nil failure:nil];
}

- (void)setImageWithURLRequest:(NSURLRequest *)urlRequest
              placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholderImage
                       success:(void (^)(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse * _Nullable response, UIImage *image))success
                       failure:(void (^)(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError *error))failure
{

    if ([urlRequest URL] == nil) {
        [self cancelImageDownloadTask];
        self.image = placeholderImage;
        return;
    }

    if ([self isActiveTaskURLEqualToURLRequest:urlRequest]){
        return;
    }

    [self cancelImageDownloadTask];

    AFImageDownloader *downloader = [[self class] sharedImageDownloader];
    id <AFImageRequestCache> imageCache = downloader.imageCache;

    //Use the image from the image cache if it exists
    UIImage *cachedImage = [imageCache imageforRequest:urlRequest withAdditionalIdentifier:nil];
    if (cachedImage) {
        if (success) {
            success(urlRequest, nil, cachedImage);
        } else {
            self.image = cachedImage;
        }
        [self clearActiveDownloadInformation];
    } else {
        if (placeholderImage) {
            self.image = placeholderImage;
        }

        __weak __typeof(self)weakSelf = self;
        NSUUID *downloadID = [NSUUID UUID];
        AFImageDownloadReceipt *receipt;
        receipt = [downloader
                   downloadImageForURLRequest:urlRequest
                   withReceiptID:downloadID
                   success:^(NSURLRequest * _Nonnull request, NSHTTPURLResponse * _Nullable response, UIImage * _Nonnull responseObject) {
                       __strong __typeof(weakSelf)strongSelf = weakSelf;
                       if ([strongSelf.af_activeImageDownloadReceipt.receiptID isEqual:downloadID]) {
                           if (success) {
                               success(request, response, responseObject);
                           } else if(responseObject) {
                               strongSelf.image = responseObject;
                           }
                           [strongSelf clearActiveDownloadInformation];
                       }

                   }
                   failure:^(NSURLRequest * _Nonnull request, NSHTTPURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
                       __strong __typeof(weakSelf)strongSelf = weakSelf;
                        if ([strongSelf.af_activeImageDownloadReceipt.receiptID isEqual:downloadID]) {
                            if (failure) {
                                failure(request, response, error);
                            }
                            [strongSelf clearActiveDownloadInformation];
                        }
                   }];

        self.af_activeImageDownloadReceipt = receipt;
    }
}
```

Comment: please show your code

Comment: Can you show your code? I think maybe you add thumbnail image into parent view. Please check your objects again.

Comment: I have added some code segments. Hope those will be enough

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement left swipe action, I suggest you should : **Use** `-tableView:trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAtIndexPath:` instead of this method, which will be deprecated in a future release.
This method (`editActionsForRowAtIndexPath`) supersedes `-tableView:titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:` if return value is non-nil

Example of use of `-tableView:trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
if (indexPath.section == 0) {
    UIContextualAction *deleteRowAction = [UIContextualAction contextualActionWithStyle:UIContextualActionStyleDestructive title:@"Delete" handler:^(UIContextualAction * _Nonnull action, __kindof UIView * _Nonnull sourceView, void (^ _Nonnull completionHandler)(BOOL)) {
        //e.g. [self.dataArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        //e.g. [self.tableView reloadData];
        completionHandler (YES);
    }];
    UISwipeActionsConfiguration *config = [UISwipeActionsConfiguration configurationWithActions:@[deleteRowAction]];
    return config;
} else {
    //...
}
```

Comment: My application uses iOS 9.0 as the minimum deployment target. I have a issue with using this method since this is supporting only iOS 11 and upper versions.